# Apache server 2.4.7

Tags: linux, apache

While I am running my first program in Apache /2.4.7 (ubuntu) it shows error as  Follows:

Not Found  The requested URL /hello was not found on this server.  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80.

I tried changing apache2.conf as below:

Options ExecCGI Indexes 
        FollowSymLinks <------
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        AddHandler cgi-script  .py       <--------

Still not able execute my program ?

Thanks

Comment: The file ´hello´ exists on your drive and is in the /var/www folder? If you're trying to run a cgi script, try acessing `hello.cgi`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little info provided, there are a couple things to try:

- Seems like you are trying to load a Python script, so include the extension of the script filename in the URL. As in: `http://127.0.0.1/hello.py`
- Check for owner and permissions for the script. Does Apache have access to execute them?